# What is $k[G]$ when $G$ is an algebraic group (notation)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation, definition, algebraic-groups

Let $G = GL_2(k)$ for simplicity where $k$ is an algebarically closed field. 
When $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ is an affine variety $k[X] = k[x_1, ..., x_n]/I(X)$ where $I(X) = \{ f\in k[x_1, ..., x_n] : f(P) = 0 \ \forall P \in X \}$. So what does it mean when people use the notation $k[G]$?

In this case is it that 
$$
k[G] = O_{\mathbb{A}^4}(U)
$$
where 
$U = \{ ad - bc \not = 0 \}$?

Comment: Usually it would refer to the Hopf Algebra representing the group functor. For  example, when $G= \operatorname{GL}_{1}(k)$--the multiplicative group-- then $k(G) = k[x, 1/x]$. For $G = \operatorname{GL}_2(k)$, $k[G]= k[x,y,w,z]/(det(x,y,w,z)-1)$.

Comment: For $G = GL_2$ I thought it was $k[G] = k[ a, b, c, d , 1/(ad-bc) ]$... Is this the same as what you have with quotient?

Answer (score 1):

If $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$ is an affine scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$, then $k[X]=A$. 
Now, if $G$ is an affine group scheme, say $G=\operatorname{Spec}B$, then we still have that $k[G] = B$. However, since $G$ is an affine group schemes, the underlying $k$-algebra $B$ must have the structure of a Hopf algebra over $k$.

Here are some examples:

$$ \operatorname{GL}(1,k) = \operatorname{Spec} k[x,1/x], \ \ \ \ k[\operatorname{GL}(1,k)] = k[x, 1/x]$$

$$ \operatorname{GL}(2,k) = \operatorname{Spec} k[x,y,w,z,1/(xz-yw))], \ \ \ k[\operatorname{GL}(2,k)] = k[x,y,w,z,1/(xz-yw))]$$ 
$$\operatorname{SL}(2,k)= \operatorname{Spec} k[x,y,w,z]/(xz-yw), \ \ \ k[\operatorname{SL}(2,k)]=k[x,y,w,z]/(xz-yw-1)  $$